# Laravel - Architecture on how to find out last login of user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been looking for a way to check when users have been active on my website. My first idea is to create a datetime field on the database called "last login", every time the user would log in, it would update.

Seems fine, but when a user has a 'keep me logged in' token, the session will remain active and he won't have to to through the login process for a while, compromising the accuracy of the active date (I might send an email "We miss you" when in reality he's an active user)

The other approach I thought was to have some key actions which would trigger the 'active' saving, but then again, the user could not do some of these actions, having the same problem.

Since I can't update the field in every user action for performance reasons, what would be a good approach for this? What do the pros use?

Edit: I know Laravel has some authentication classes; do any of these functions activate when the user comes back (even if he is still logged in)?

Comment: Found this: http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/08/02/laravel-tracking-last-activity-date-of-authorised-user/ But it's very outdated, I'm trying to do it in laravel 5

Comment: You can use a key-value store like `RocksDB` to store login information rather than mySQL(performance taken into consideration). Update this value as needed.

Comment: You could use cookies...

Comment: @Renzo cookies won't help if OP wants to send some emails based on last login of user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can listen on the **auth.login** event that is triggered for login with both **credentials** and **remember me** token. Once it's fired, you'd need to update the last login date.

First, create the listener:

```
class UpdateLastLoginDate {
  public function handle($user) {
    $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
  }
}
```

Then register the listener in your **EventServiceProvider**:

```
protected $listen = [
  'auth.login' => [
        UpdateLastLoginDate::class
    ]
];
```

**Update** 
Since version 5.2, you must add the Event class name as the array key, and access the user as a property of the event object passed:

```
protected $listen = [
  'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        UpdateLastLoginDate::class
    ]
];


class UpdateLastLoginDate {
  public function handle($event) {
    $user = $event->user;
    $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
  }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade (scroll to events)

Comment: I'm sorry, when I said "remember me" I meant "keep me logged in".. this will keep the session active, right? Will auth.login still hear if the session is active? Seems like a good solution if it would work..

Comment: Also, I found this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#terminable-middleware , maybe it can update the timestamp after the response is returned to the browser, having no impact on the user's end (just flooding the database with connections)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep me logged in" vs. "remember me" :) "Remember me" token will keep user authenticate automatically after session ends, e.g. when they close the browser or do not refresh the page for some longer time.

Comment: You could do this in the middleware, but this way you'd update the user in the database with every request. So it would be more precise, but result in higher number of db queries (+1 query for every user for every page view). You could of course count the requests in the session, update the user every N requests, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: Ok, what I meant is.. for exemple when I log into my facebook account, it rarely logs out, I have to do it manually if I want to. I want my website to have the same behaviour, I don't really know if that is a "remember me" behavior or "keep me logged in" (or if it's the same thing haha)

Comment: The middleware solution seems a bit heavy on the system.. I'll try to test it listening to the event.

Comment: Hmm, regardless how you call it, it seems like the same feature. Speaking of performance, listener is ligher solution, yet a bit less precise. Still, for 99% of the users the accuracy would be +- session lifetime, which is usually 30 minutes, unless you have a user that keeps refreshing the page for ages. In real world you'd probably want to send the email after N days of inactivity so such accuracy should be enough

Comment: Great explanation! For some reason I thought the session would be infinite (which makes no sense now) and it would never reauthorize. So, if I put the code to save the last_login in the auth middleware, it will also be called when the user authenticates via remember me, right?

Comment: Yes, it will be called at the end of every request

Comment: Carbon::new() should be Carbon::now()

Comment: This is what I needed too- thank you @jedrzej.kurylo!